# jQuery multiple class elements controlled by specific buttons

Tags: jquery, html, events, class

Its a hard question to word i dont even know where to start explaining, however il right the code for you

This works

```
<div>
    <div>
        <img src='' class='myImage'/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class='btn' src='hello.png'>Hello</button>
        <button class='btn' src='hi.png'>Hi</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.btn').click(function (){
    $('.myImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Now what if i have multiple images

```
<div>
    <div>
        <img src='' class='myImage'/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class='btn' src='hello.png'>Hello</button>
        <button class='btn' src='hi.png'>Hi</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <img src='' class='myImage'/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class='btn' src='hello.png'>Hello</button>
        <button class='btn' src='hi.png'>Hi</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Id cant work here, cause the divs are drawn using dynamic database and PHP. Is there a way i can get the btn event that is clicked to only change the source of its parents `myImage`

Comment: Actually you won't change the sourse of its **parents**. The image is in the same level as btn. The parents is just divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a different selector to ensure you get the correct `img.myImage`.

Probably this will work:

```
$('.btn').click(function (e){
    var $this = $(this); //small performance gain
    $this.closest('img.myImage').attr('src', $this.attr('src'));
});
```

Worth noting that `.closest` is only available in jQuery 1.3 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.btn').click(function (){
  var btn = $(this);
  btn.parent().prev().children().attr('src', btn.attr('src'));
});
```

This way you get to parent div, then to previous div (there are two) and finally to child of that previous div.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way would be to use the JQuery `parent()` method, for which you can find documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).  If your HTML structure was constant, you could just walk up two elements like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev().children('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

..or, if you wanted something more dynamic, you could put a class name or ID on each parent div and use the `parent(selector)` variation in the documentation.

Comment: The parent in any level of .btn is not an image so this code will not work.

Comment: @SPL_Splinter: Thanks, it was an oversight from typing fast; it's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). If you have one `.myImage` for each `.btn` the image 3 is relative to button 3, the image 666 is relative to button 666 and so on.

```
$('.btn').click(function (){
    var id = $('.btn').index(this);
    $('.myImage').eq(id).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```